# AIR Native Extension - Missing implementation for platform: Android-ARM

Tags: android, compiler-errors, adt, air-native-extension

I'm trying to compile an ANE for Android but I got this error no matter what I try.

***"Missing implementation for platform: Android-ARM"***

Windows 7 PRO
I'm using Flash Builder 4.7 with AIR sdk 3.7,
the android jar is packaged using the latest android sdk with eclipse,
this is the command line I'm using according to guides and tutorials I found:

`adt -package -target ane ANEBitmapEncoder.ane extension.xml -swc DataExchange.swc -plattform Android-ARM Android-ARM/ANEBitmapEncoder.jar Android-ARM/library.swf`

so my file structure is:

```
Android-ARM (dir)
    ANEBitmapEncoder.jar
    library.swf
DataExchange.swc
extension.xml
```

and finally that my extension.xml:

```
<extension xmlns="http://ns.adobe.com/air/extension/3.7">
  <id>com.adobe.BitmapEncoderExtension</id>
  <versionNumber>1</versionNumber>
  <platforms>
      <platform name="Android-ARM">
      <applicationDeployment>
        <nativeLibrary>BitmapEncoderExtension.jar</nativeLibrary>
        <initializer>com.adobe.BitmapEncoderExtension</initializer>
        <finalizer>com.adobe.BitmapEncoderExtension</finalizer>
      </applicationDeployment>
    </platform>
  </platforms>
</extension>
```

Is there some one that can help me with this? Is any other information required to try to understand the problem? It's the first time I have to complile an ANE so I have really no clue.

Thank you very much and regards,
Gianpiero

Comment: Hi Gianpiero, the name of the .jar file in extension.xml seems different from the .jar in the command line - could that be it?

Comment: Hi roll, as you pointed out the jar name file is wrong.. and after a more careful look the command line is wrong too.
It's -platform, not -plattform ...
The devil is in the detail.
Now my ANE comunicate with the AIR project, it took a while before setting everything.
Thank you!

Comment: Please mark the question as answered if so.

Comment: I'd like to do it, but I can't find any button or other links that let me flag this question an "answered". can you help me SNce? thanks

Comment: You need to create an answer and then mark as answered